# Running a Selenium Script on Python Anywhere:

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pythonanywhere

I am trying to schedule a python script that uses Selenium to scrape the web on PythonAnywhere.

I am getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55bde1d40e89 <unknown>
```

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
# Sets our default browser to chrome, passing in specific options such as download directory
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Change download directory to wherever this program is on your machine
cwd = os.getcwd()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Set our preferred options for chrome webdriver
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : cwd}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Python 3.9.10

Note: This script works on my local machine without the additional chome_options.add_argument(X) lines.

I believe I am running selenium 4.8.0 (at least on my local machine)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

EDIT: My Script now begins to run, but I am getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x563891898e89 <unknown>
```

Is this because pythonanywhere has a approved list of sites and I am a free user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that error is likely because you are trying to access a site that is not on the PythonAnywhere allowlist. Search the PythonAnywhere help pages for "allowlist" for how to request additions and the requirements for a site to be added to the allowlist